# Can we use join with in same table while using group by function?

Tags: sql, oracle

For instance, I have a table with columns below:

```
pk_id,address,first_name,last_name
```

and I have a query like this to display the first name ans last name that are repetitive(duplicates)

```
select first_name,last_name
from table 
group by first_name,last_name
having count(*)>1;
```

but the above query just returns first and last names but I want to display pk_id and address too that are tied to these duplicate first and last names
Can we use joins to do this on the same table.Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of doing is to build a view with the `pk_id` and the count of duplicates. Once you have it, it is only a matter of using a `JOIN` on the base table, and a filter to only keep rows having a duplicate:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM T
JOIN (SELECT "pk_id", 
       COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY "first_name", "last_name") cnt
       FROM T) V
ON T."pk_id" = V."pk_id"
WHERE cnt > 1
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ecd0/9

Answer (score 0):

You have to call it from an outer query, like this:

```
select * from table
where first_name||last_name in
    (select first_name||last_name from
        (select first_name, last_name, count( * )
         from table
         group by first_name,last_name
         having count( * ) > 1
        )
    )
```

note: you may not need to concatenate the 2 fields, but I haven't tested thaT.

Comment: The string concatenation trick may produce incorrect results for some data. For example, `'FRANK' || 'AFKA' = 'FRAN' || 'KAFKA'`.

Comment: True. You'd want to add a space to avoid that, as in first_name||' '||last_name. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: You can use this condition: `(first_name, last_name) in (select first_name, last_name...`

Answer (score 0):

```
with
  my_duplicates as
  (
    select
      first_name,
      last_name
    from
      my_table
    group by
      first_name,
      last_name
    having
      count(*) > 1
  )
select
  bb.pk_id,
  bb.address,
  bb.first_name,
  bb.last_name
from
  my_duplicates aa
  join my_table bb on
  (
    aa.first_name = bb.first_name
    and
    aa.last_name = bb.last_name
  )
order by
  bb.last_name,
  bb.first_name,
  bb.pk_id
```